# Find route from starting point and return to start point

Tags: php, algorithm, data-structures, logic

EXAMPLE 1

### This is data we give to PHP script (strings)

```
T1_P8,
T1_P2, 
T1_P3,
P8_P3,
```

This data can be in array like:

```
$TUBEDATA=array("t1_p8","t1_p2","t1_p3","t8_p3");
```

Now the script must extract all from data and output all possible combinations on screen.
The rule for combinations is if we start with T1 we must end with T1 and we need to pass all combinations available.
The output for the above data should be:

```
T1 -> P8 -> P3 -> T1
T1 -> P3 -> P8 -> T1
P8 -> T1 -> P3 -> P8
P8 -> P3 -> T1 -> P8
```

EXAMPLE 2

If we add new value to TUBEDATA

```
T1_P8,
T1_P2,
T1_P3,
P8_P3,
P2_P3 <-new value
```

This data can be in array like:

```
$TUBEDATA=array("t1_p8","t1_p2","t1_p3","t8_p3",“p2_p3“);
```

Then we have many more combinations and output should be:

```
T1 -> P8 -> P3 -> T1
T1 -> P3 -> P8 -> T1
P8 -> T1 -> P3 -> P8
P8 -> P3 -> T1 -> P8
T1 -> P2 -> P3 -> T1            
T1 -> P2 -> P3 -> P8 -> T1       
P2 ->T1 ->P8 ->P3 ->P2            
P2 ->T1 ->P3 ->P2                      
P2 ->P3 ->P8 ->T1 ->P2           
P2 ->P3 ->T1 ->P2
```

What need to take care of is not to create a loop.
Example of loop (invalid combination):

```
T1 -> P8 -> P3 -> P8 -> P3 -> T1
```

If we have allredy `P8` present we dont go again to it.

### what i did so far

```
$given_data = array("t1_p8", "t1_p2", "t1_p3", "p8_p3");

$array_index = 3;

$visited = array();

$current_index = 0;

$current_data = explode("_",$given_data[$array_index]);

$starting_point = $current_data[0];//t1
$search_point =  $current_data[1];//p8

$generated_rout =  $starting_point."->".$search_point;

$round = true;

$i = 0;

do {

    if( $current_index == $i ){
        $i++;
        continue;
    }

    $pointing_data = explode("_",$given_data[$i]);

    $t1 = $pointing_data[0];
    $t2 = $pointing_data[1];

    if( $search_point == $t1 ){
        $current_index = $i;
        $generated_rout .= "->".$t2;
        if( $starting_point == $t2 ){
            break;
        }
        $search_point = $t2;
        $i = 0;

    }
    elseif( $search_point == $t2 ){
        $current_index = $i;
        $generated_rout .= "->".$t1;
        if( $starting_point == $t1 ){
            break;
        }
        $search_point = $t1;
        $i = 0;
    }
    else{
        $i++;
    }

} while ( $i < 4 );

echo $generated_rout;
```

the problem with my logic is i can find routes only from one direction but when i try to find with vise versa condition like swapping of $starting_point & $search_point its not generating the proper results.

**Please help me for solving above issue with php code and thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be easily solved by the logic of graphs. Let's understand the problem nicely by looking at an example.

Example:-

```
T1_P8,
T1_P2, 
T1_P3,
P8_P3
```

Now let's split (explode) each string as these are the starting and ending points and are separated by underscore.

So our vertices will be - `T1, P8, P2, P3`

Also the graph seems to be undirected as I understand from the example.

Now if we were to visualize this example in terms of graph, if would look something like this:-

```
                T1 ---- P8
             /    \       |
            /      \      |
           /        \     |
           P2          P3
```

So, from the diagram it's clear that are 4 edges:-

```
T1 - P8
T1 - P2
T1 - P3
P3 - P8
```

Now Once you create the graph, just start your dfs on each and every node and keep a `visited` array in order to keep track of all the nodes that you have visited, this will stop you from looping again through that node.

Now I won't be coding the whole code for you, this much I expect you to try, now that the concept becomes clear to you.

Let me know in the comment, what do you think.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much for your help but i want to return to staring point after visiting the nodes (find the all possible ways ) and dfs is just for visiting all the nodes so how can i return to starting point?